# array not Display Same positions

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

post1  |  Post 2  |  Custom Ads

<br>

Custom Ads  |  post 3  |   post4

display Ads Same positions In Wordpress Website

Array is not displaying properly due to which the layout of the design is too much out

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAX6u.png)

```
<?php $count = 0; 
$ad_positions = [3,4]; // enter the desired positions
$ads = [
    '<div class="dp-in swiper-slide">
        <div class="listing-car-item">
            <div class="listing-car-item-inner">
                <img decoding="async" class="img-responsive s" src="https://www.splitarts.net/smr/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/deal.png">
                <h3>looking for a deal?</h3>
                <p>save big on discounted cars.</p>
                <a class="elementor-button elementor-button-link elementor-size-sm" href="#"><span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"><span class="elementor-button-text">SHOP DEALS</span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>',
    '<div class="dp-in swiper-slide">
        <div class="listing-car-item">
            <div class="listing-car-item-inner">
            <img decoding="async" class="img-responsive s" src="https://www.splitarts.net/smr/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/trade.png">
            <h3>looking for a deal?</h3>
            <p>save big on discounted cars.</p>
            <a class="elementor-button elementor-button-link elementor-size-sm" href="#"><span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"><span class="elementor-button-text">SHOP DEALS</span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>',
    // and so on
  ];

while ( $special_query->have_posts() ) :
                    
                    ?>

                    <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { 
                        $count++;
                        if( in_array( $count, $ad_positions ) ){
                          $ad = array_shift( $ads ); // gets and removes the first ad from the array
                          echo $ad ; 
                        }
                    }
                 ?>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.